# Difference between two variable one is assigned a value undefined and second one is only declared a var not initialized

Tags: javascript, undefined

What is different between two `variable` one is assigned a value `undefined` and second one is only `declared` a `var` not initiased ?

```
var a = undefined;
var b;
a === b;  // returns true
```

What is different between two variable `a` and `b`?

```
var ar = new Array(4); // ar = 0[undefined × 4]
ar[0] = null; // ar = [null, undefined × 3]
ar[1] = undefined; // ar = [null, undefined, undefined × 2]

ar.filter(function(item, index, arr){
  return item == undefined;
}); // [null, undefined]
```

I know Array's filter function runs for only initialized index.

How javascript internally check that `ar[1]` is assigend `undefined` so run filter for this and `ar[2]` is unassigned `undefined` so dont run for this ?

Comment: `implicit` and `explicit` assignment to `undefined`. Does that _matter_?

Comment: Then why this implicit undefined not working for array's filter ? I think it matters in case of array filter function

Comment: Who did down vote. Please explain why ?

Comment: "How javascript internally check that ar[1] is assigend undefined " ? `if(n in ar)`

Answer (score 1):

There are three separate issues going on here:

1. A regular variable that has just been declared, but not assigned a value will report `undefined` when you read that variable.  That is essentially its default value.
2. You have to be very careful when comparing `null` with `==` because you will find that `null == undefined` is `true` because of auto-type conversion.  So, if you want to filter on only `undefined` elements, you have to use `item === undefined` in the filter.
3. `.filter()` only iterates elements in the array that have actually been assigned a value.  Unlike plain variables, there is a difference between an array element that has assigned a value and one that has never been assigned a value and `.filter()` knows to skip the ones that have never been assigned a value (the ones that are essentially "sparse").

Here's some more detail on these three issues:

A variable that has been declared, but not explicitly initialized, has a value of `undefined`.  That is its default value.

This, this code is as expected:

```
var a = undefined;
var b;
a === b;  // returns true
```

Then, in your second code block, if you want to truly test for whether something is `undefined`, then you need to use `===`, not `==` to avoid any type conversion.

```js
var ar = new Array(4); // ar = 0[undefined × 4]
ar[0] = null; // ar = [null, undefined × 3]
ar[1] = undefined; // ar = [null, undefined, undefined × 2]

var result = ar.filter(function(item, index, arr){
  return item === undefined;
}); 

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
   document.write(i, ": ", result[i], "<br>");
}
```

Note: `.filter()` will skip elements of the array that have not been initialized to have any value, thus they will never even be considered in the `.filter()` operation.  If you try to read their values, you will get `undefined`, but `.filter()` knows the difference between a "sparse" array value that has never been assigned anything.  It has to do with whether the array key exists or not, not what the value is and thus it is different for array items than it is for plain variables.

From the [MDN doc for `.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> The range of elements processed by filter() is set before the first
>   invocation of callback. Elements which are appended to the array after
>   the call to filter() begins will not be visited by callback. If
>   existing elements of the array are changed, or deleted, their value as
>   passed to callback will be the value at the time filter() visits them;
>   **elements that are deleted are not visited**.

Here's a demonstration of how the array keys do not actually exist until someting is assigned to the array element.  This is the information that `.filter()` uses to know what to iterate and what to skip:

```js
var ar = new Array(4);
ar[1] = "foo";
ar[2] = undefined;

for (var index in ar) {
  document.write(index, ": ", ar[index], "<br>");     // 1 foo, 2 undefined
}
```

Note that indexes 0 and 3 are not iterated with the `for` loop because those keys do not exist in the array.  The array is "sparse".  Only some elements actually exist.

Comment: I know this ....filter() will skip elements of the array that have not been initialized to have any value that is having undefined. Then how javascript recognize undefined values between two one is explicitly assigned and another is implicitly assigned ?

Comment: @intekhab - I had trouble understanding what you were really asking in your question so I worked through each piece and I think I have now covered the issues.

Comment: @intekhab - please read the end of the paragraph in my answer that starts with "Note:".

Comment: @intekhab - There's nothing wrong with an array value that contains the value `null`.  That is a valid value.  You may be getting yourself confused because `null == undefined` is true due to auto-type conversion, but `null === undefined` is false.  This is yet another reason why you should nearly always use `===`.

Comment: This is in your note : knows the difference between a "sparse" array value that has never been assigned anything... My question is how javascript does the same internally ?

Comment: @intekhab - It says this in my answer: "It has to do with whether the array key exists or not, not what the value is and thus it is different for array items than it is for plain variables."  When you do `var ar = new Array(4);`, that sets `.length` to `4`, but it does not create the array keys `[0]`, [1]`, `[2]` and `[3]` until you actually assign something to that array element.  So, if the array key does not exist, `.filter()` will skip the element.